# How I should to refresh table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have some table on scrollPane and some of my cells are painted to different colors. When I clicked to the cell in the some row that row, or rows should change their color, but repainting works well only when I scroll my table if several rows should be colored.
How I can to do full update for JTable after repainting cells by overriding getTableCellRenderrerComponent()?
Thanks.

my table class:

```
    class MyGrid extends JTable {
    private TNotifyEvent onCustomDrawCell;

    public MyGrid() {
        this.setSelectionMode(0);
    }

    public TNotifyEvent getOnCustomDrawCell() {
        return this.onCustomDrawCell;
    }

    public void setOnCustomDrawCell(TNotifyEvent onCustomDrawCell) {
        this.onCustomDrawCell = onCustomDrawCell;
    }
}
```

use of my table

```
 MyGrid table = new MyGrid();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

 table.setOnCustomDrawCell(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel();

                @Override
                public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                                                               boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                    lbl = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                    lbl.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                    MyItem item = new MyItem();
                    item.setValue((Vector) model.getDataVector().get(row));
                    item.setCanvas(lbl);
                    MutableBoolean aDoneMutable = new MutableBoolean(false);
                    getContentStyle(null, item, item.getCanvas(), null);
                    drawCells(null, item.getCanvas(), item, aDoneMutable);
                    return lbl;
                }
            });
        }
     return true;
    });

    public static void getContentStyle(Object Sender, MyItem ARecord, JLabel AItem, TcxStyle AStyle) {
    try {
        if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ARecord.getValue().get(3))) == 0) {
            AItem.setOpaque(true);
            AItem.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        } else if (ARecord.getValue().get(4).equals("222")) {
            AItem.setOpaque(true);
            AItem.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        } else {
            AItem.setOpaque(true);
            AItem.setBackground(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public static void drawCells(Object Sender, JLabel ACanvas, MyItem AViewInfo, final MutableBoolean mutableADone) {
    boolean ADone = mutableADone.getValue();
    try {
        if((AViewInfo.getValue().get(4).equals("44")) && (!AViewInfo.isSelected())) {
            ACanvas.setForeground(Color.black);
            ACanvas.setOpaque(true);
            ACanvas.setBackground(PictureUtils.createColorfromString("$CCE6FF"));
            AViewInfo.setCanvas(ACanvas);
        } else {
            if((AViewInfo.getValue().get(5).equals("555")) &&  (AViewInfo.isSelected()) && (AViewInfo.isHasFocus())) {
                ACanvas.setOpaque(true);
                ACanvas.setBackground(PictureUtils.createColorfromString("$CCE6FF"));
                AViewInfo.setCanvas(ACanvas);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    mutableADone.setValue(ADone);
}
```

Also myItem class:

```
    class MyItem {
    private String columnName;
    private Vector value;
    private JLabel canvas;
    private Integer index;
    private boolean isSelected;
    private boolean hasFocus;

    public MyItem() {
    }

    public String getColumnName() {
        return this.columnName;
    }

    public void setColumnName(String columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }

    public Vector getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(Vector value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public JLabel getCanvas() {
        return this.canvas;
    }

    public void setCanvas(JLabel canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return this.isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.isSelected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isHasFocus() {
        return this.hasFocus;
    }

    public void setHasFocus(boolean hasFocus) {
        this.hasFocus = hasFocus;
    }

    public Integer getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }

    public void setIndex(Integer index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

I tried to use tableChange() listener, but it throws stackOverflow error before shows my table

**EDIT**
Also I forgot to say: when I debugging my code the table is colored well.
And table repaint anywhere except scrollPane viewport.

Comment: Solved. I just need to do update viewport of my scroll

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you change a proper of a Swing component you need to tell the component to repaint itself:

```
public void setOnCustomDrawCell(TNotifyEvent onCustomDrawCell) {
    this.onCustomDrawCell = onCustomDrawCell;
    repaint(); // added this
}
```

Comment: I gave you the basic concept of how Swing components work. All scrolling does is tell the table to repaint certain rows. So somewhere in your code you must be changing the data of the table (or your MyItem class) and you are not repainting the table. The code you posted doesn't help because we don't know the context of how that code is used and how the data is changed and added to the table. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the `"concept"` of what you are trying to do.